Tab completion with wildcards
Assuming I have the following directory structure:
myUser@myRaspi:~/Development/Gitea/RaspiConfig/Docker $ ls
10-nginx              30-openHAB       40-RaspiFanController  40-Snowflake       Configure.ps1    DC_All_Pull.ps1     DC_All_Up.ps1                       DC_nginx_Restart.ps1
20-ScreenshotCreator  40-JoplinServer  40-ShopAndEat          40-ThisIsYourLife  DC_All_Down.ps1  DC_All_Restart.ps1  DC_Current_PullAndRestartNginx.ps1

Now I'd like to cd into the directory for Joplin Server and since I forgot the number prefix, I enter cd *Joplin* and hit TAB.
I'd expect that bash completes this to cd 40-JoplinServer, but nothing happens. When entering cd 40-J and hitting TAB, it works as expected.
Can I somehow change this, i. e. auto-complete using wildcards on TAB?
Thx!

Questions about using the shell are more appropriate to Unix & Linux but I will answer this one quickly.
For future reference, the default user shell on RpiOS is bash, which has been around for 30+ years; currently in major version 5, but most of the features have been around since 2, early 2000's.  It has a much wider context of use (per wikipedia, it was also the default MacOS shell until 5 years ago) and there have been stacks of books written on it not to mention probably enough online docs, tutorials etc. to spend the rest of your life reading.
Bash implements a superset of the POSIX shell protocol, which is also implemented in a more strict minimal form by dash, which is what sh invokes on RpiOS (beware the difference if you are scripting).

I enter cd *Joplin* and hit TAB.

Those asterisk wildcards are for shell globbing which is part of the POSIX protocol and in command-line bash, at least, they are not tab-expandable.
Globbing has its own rules (ie., it isn't regular expression based, etc.).

When entering cd 40-J and hitting TAB, it works as expected.

Bash does do this kind of completion.
If you want more a more dynamic command-line interface, you might want to look at fish (note that "Finally, a command line shell for the 90s" is a bit satirical; fish first appeared in 2005), which amongst other things does exactly the kind of completion you are looking for (tab expands shell globbing) and has been actively expanding its feature set for a decade or so.
It's available from the OS repos: sudo apt install fish.  You can then try it by switching from the command line with fish; to get out just exit.  To set it as your default (aka. login) shell:
chsh -s /usr/bin/fish
# To switch that back:
chsh -s /bin/bash

This doesn't take effect until your next login.
A caveat: While fish does implement various POSIX features such as globbing, it does not use the POSIX shell language, it has its own somewhat simpler language and so various command-line instructions you find online that are really POSIX shell/bash based may not work as is.
